# Is append() a jQuery or Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I search on the web I clearly see that `append()` is a jQuery function and the javascript equivalent is: `element.innerHTML += "text"` or `insertAdjacentHTML()`.

Can you explain that while testing when I don't load jquery, I emptied the cache and `append()` still works in a native javascript file.

This is my test :

```
var x = document.getElementById("test");
x.append("123");
```

Has `append()` been added to Javascript?

Comment: `element.innerHTML += "text"` is not equivalent to `append()`. Changing `innerHTML` will remove all the references of children of `element`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `append()` method on [Element objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) as well as [jQuery objects](https://api.jquery.com/append) so the answer is both (although the implementation is different).

Comment: **Also note:** The javascript append-method is still considered as an experimental technology by some browser-developers, but its supported by most modern browsers. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Comment: That's true, `Node.append()` is not at all supported by IE, although there is a Polyfill. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#Browser_compatibility) for more details